# Download latest version of Slack automatically

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I have a script that I download slack with the wget command, as the script runs every time a computer is configured I need to always download the latest version of slack.

i work in debian9

I'm doing it right now:

```
wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-3.3.7-amd64.deb
```

and I tried this:

```
curl -s https://slack.com/intl/es/release-notes/linux | grep "<h2>Slack" | head -1 | sed 's/[<h2>/]//g' | sed 's/[a-z A-Z]//g' | sed "s/ //g"
```

this return: 3.3.7
add this to: `wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-$curl-amd64.deb`

and not working.

Do you know why this can not work?

Comment: If the upstream doesn't provide a link, there is little you can do. You can parse the http page, but believe me, it will cost you way more time, because with each change on the http page you would have to rewrite your script, it's the same as checking the newest version and update manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script produces a long string with a lot of leading whitespace.

```
bash$ curl -s https://slack.com/intl/es/release-notes/linux |
> grep "<h2>Slack" | head -1 |
> sed 's/[<h2>/]//g' | sed 's/[a-z A-Z]//g' | sed "s/ //g"
                                    3.3.7
```

You want the string without spaces, and the fugly long pipeline can be simplified significantly.

```
barh$ curl -s https://slack.com/intl/es/release-notes/linux |
> sed -n "/^.*<h2>Slack /{;s///;s/[^0-9.].*//p;q;}"
3.3.7
```

Notice also that the character class `[<h2>/]` doesn't mean at all what you think.  It matches a single character which is `<` or `h` or `2` or `>` or `/` regardless of context.  So for example, if the current version number were to contain the digit 2, you would zap that too.

Scraping like this is very brittle, though. I notice that if I change the `/es/` in the URL to `/en/` I get no output at all. Perhaps you can find a better way to obtain the newest version (using `apt` should allow you to install the newest version without any scripting on your side).

Comment: Quick googling gets me https://repology.org/metapackage/slack/packages though I can't vouch for any of the results there.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo wget "https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-$(curl -s "https://slack.com/intl/es/release-notes/linux" | xmllint --html --xpath '//h2' - 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | sed 's/<h2>//;s#</h2>##;s/Slack //')-amd64.deb"
```

will output:

```
wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-3.3.7-amd64.deb
```

I used xmllint to parse the html and extract the first part between `<h2>` tags. Then some removing with `sed` and I receive the newest version.

@edit:

On noticing, that you could just `grep <h2>` from the site to get the version, you can the version with just:

```
curl -s "https://slack.com/intl/es/release-notes/linux" | grep -m1 "<h2>" | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

Comment: Install `xmllint`

Comment: This gets me a long sequence of version numbers. You could probably avoid the `head -n 1` with a slightly more complex `sed` script anyway, but then the `xmllint` seems superfluous anyway.

Comment: Mixing `curl` and `wget` like that is pretty hilarious (-: